# Deferred's then and other callbacks or errbacks

Tags: dojo

if I have a `dojo.Deferred` and add several callbacks to it (let us look at an successfully task) and in addition, I add a then `(function(){..});` to the Deferred,
which callback is called at first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have put together a short example to manifest the FIFO principle: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/CHQ8d/

The latest documentation: http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/Deferred

It is useful to know that when chaining callbacks the return value of the callback is passed to the following callback (see the jsFiddle for details).

Answer (score 0):

The flow will allways be any assigned functions from .addCallback first followed immediately by any functions passed in by .then.

Try it out in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/seeds/h3Hkh/)

Comment: In your answer I read that addCallback functions are called before functions assigned with then. Or do I misread your post? If I play around with fuddle, it seems to be just in the order the callbacks were assigned, independent from then and addCallback.

Comment: Actually `addCallback` is deprecated and it just calls `then`. Callbacks are being resolved [FIFO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO).

Comment: Now I understand why addCallback is deprecated ;-) then is the same as addCallback and addErrback in one function as I see it now.

Comment: Actually I just consulted Dojo 1.7.2. source code and `addCallback` is not marked as _deprecated_, but all the recent tutorials employ `then` as `Deferred` is to comply with [Promises](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Promises) API. It was two years ago at Sitepen's [blog post](http://goo.gl/DaHJR), where Kris Zyp mentioned: "Dojo’s new Deferred module provides backwards compatibility with previous versions, still providing `addCallback`, `addErrback`, `addBoth`, and `addCallbacks` methods, but these will probably be deprecated in a future release."